# How to optionally handle a modal with Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

Sometimes there is a modal window that pops up. I have this try catch to handle it and it works in headless mode. However, when I'm in VSCode, it stops when the error is thrown.

```
await test.step('Optionally click continue', async () => {
    try {
        page.getByRole('cell', { name: 'Continue' }).click({ timeout: 10000 });
    } catch (error) {

    }
});
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be6tD.png)

Is there a playwright preferred way to handle this that doesn't throw an exception? The playwright extension stops on exceptions to help debug. In this case, I would prefer a way to optionally handle a button without an exception being thrown.

Comment: What happens if you leave your catch like: `catch { };` program should continue without doing anything, which is what you expect, right? Can you share the output you get when you run your script?

Comment: Changing to `catch {}` still makes it stop when the error is thrown.

Comment: Maybe you can try `if page.isVisible('role=cell[name="Continue"i]') {//Whatever}` if it is true, then do something, if not continue

Comment: @JakyRuby Ding ding ding. Thank you! If you make it an answer, I will mark it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if page.isVisible('role=cell[name="Continue"i]') {
//Whatever
}
```

Comment: actually it's not working. The isVisible check gets executed and returns false. Eventually the modal with the continue button shows up and it doesn't get clicked. I think I need something more like "keep checking for X seconds for the continue button"

Answer (score 0):

check waitForSelector in https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector

and if you are alert, prompt or any other dialog
https://playwright.dev/docs/dialogs